# How to return unauthorized using Laravel API Authentication

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel API authentication with a token. (as explained here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/api-authentication#protecting-routes)

I am running some tests with Postman and it works fine. When I try to access the route without a valid token, I see that the response is the (html of the) login page of my app. How can I return a `Unauthorized` message instead of the complete login page? Do I have to create a custom middleware?

**Controller**

```php
class ExampleController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api');
    }

    public function show(Request $request) {
        return response()->json($request->user()->name);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you use [Laravel 5.6](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#protecting-routes) or lower, add the method in the class `Handler` in `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`:

```
/**
 * Convert an authentication exception into an unauthenticated response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException  $exception
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
    }

    return redirect()->guest(route('login'));
}
```

And also add the following line above the class in the same file as mentioned above:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
```

In the postman within the headers section please add the following header:

```
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

Comment: The method was already there, I missed the header `X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest` thanks!

Comment: this handle unauthenticated but the question was about unauthorized

Answer (score 12):

For people using [Laravel 6](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication#protecting-routes)
or higher ([Laravel 8](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#redirecting-unauthenticated-users), [Laravel 10](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authentication#redirecting-unauthenticated-users))
Add an "unauthenticated" function inside `app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate` like so:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;

class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string|null
     */
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('login');
        }
    }

    // Add new method 
    protected function unauthenticated($request, array $guards)
    {
        abort(response()->json(
            [
                'api_status' => '401',
                'message' => 'UnAuthenticated',
            ], 401));
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, is that somewhere documented?
Edit: found it-->
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication

Comment: that is an old link matching the other answer on this thread. On laravel > 6 it's different: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authentication

Answer (score 4):

Be sure to be sending the right headers in your request

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

Answer (score 1):

Laravel 8 update:

default handler already handle this scenario

File: `\Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler.php`

```
/**
 * Convert an authentication exception into a response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException  $exception
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    return $request->expectsJson()
                ? response()->json(['message' => $exception->getMessage()], 401)
                : redirect()->guest($exception->redirectTo() ?? route('login'));
}
```

This is how Laravel do `expectsJson` in `\Illuminate\Http\Concerns\InteractsWithContentTypes.php`

```
/**
 * Determine if the current request probably expects a JSON response.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function expectsJson()
{
    return ($this->ajax() && ! $this->pjax() && $this->acceptsAnyContentType()) || $this->wantsJson();
}


/**
 * Determine if the current request is asking for JSON.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function wantsJson()
{
    $acceptable = $this->getAcceptableContentTypes();

    return isset($acceptable[0]) && Str::contains($acceptable[0], ['/json', '+json']);
}
```

So note that content type header of request is useless. The header useful is "Accept: application/json"

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are sending correct headers

```
Accept        application/json
```

Also, you can create your own Middleware for this.